# How to extract concatenated SMS message send history from MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics, mobileconnect

Is there a way to extract the full text of a SMS messages that were sent to customers?

I'm trying to create an automation that would create a history of all SMS messages that were sent to the customer.

The "SMS Message Detail Report" is pretty much useless if you are using the "Concatenate Message" settings for your sends. This report creates separate rows for each of the parts of the message and the ID that is assigned to them seems to be assigned in a random order.

For example if you had a message with parts A, B & C the corresponding IDs can be 3, 1 & 2,  so there's no way to correctly concatenate those parts using an ascending or descending order.

Has anyone encountered custom extracts or other solutions that show the full the contents of text message that was delivered to a customer?

Comment: Did you execute the send by an API request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! There is now an 'Ordinal' field in the data view which would allow you to join the messages back together in the correct order. [_SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. How and if outbound/inbound messages are split depends on the carrier that handles your short/long code. I've heard that in some cases whole message is displayed, but I only encountered random splitting in projects I worked on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also confirmed this with SF support:

> "I understand your concern that you are looking for report/data view which will give you the result of the concatenation message in single row but unfortunately, there won't be any data view which provide this data in single row.
>
> This reports are fetched from the backend table which gives the same results of split messages, hence they are downloaded as it is in reports."