# SendSplitID values missing in SMSMessageTracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, mobileconnect, data-views

I'm trying to find a way to get full, concatenated text messages from the data available in Marketing Cloud. This was [not possible before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225000/how-to-extract-concatenated-sms-message-send-history-from-mobileconnect), but since then the [SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5#mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking) has become available which I was hoping could solve this problem (without embedding ampscript logging sends in each text message).

The column `MobileMessageTrackingID` would seem to be a good candidate as an id, but I've found records that were split into 3 parts with this id assigned randomly (the 3 parts in order present the middle, start and end of the messages). This means I can't get an ascending or descending order of parts and concatenate them and be sure about the results.

The documentation for this data view mentions the following columns:

- `SendSplitID` - If the message was split, the ID of the split
- `SendSegmentID` - The ID of the segment tied to the message

None of the records I checked contained data in those columns which makes it impossible to concatenate messages based on the information available in this data view.

I would like to know if it's a normal situation that those values are empty or if it somehow can get enabled by support.

Comment: We have had the same situation however the IDs were populated but have the same value so doesn't really help much. It looks to me this feature got released way too early :/

Comment: Is still the same happening ?